# Find first unique character in a string in Elixir

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, elixir

Given a string that contains only lowercase English letters, I am writing an Elixir function that finds the first non-repeating character in it and returns its index or else -1.

Examples:

s = "leetcode"
should return 0 because "l" is the first character that does not repeat and the zero-based index is 0

s = "loveleetcode"
should return 2 because v is the first character that does not repeat and the zero-based index is 2

The following is my solution so far, can you make it better or fix it?

```
defmodule Algos do
  def first_unique_char_index(str) do
    
    arr = String.split(str, "", trim: true)
    indexes = Enum.with_index(arr)

    first = Enum.frequencies(arr)
    |> Map.to_list
    |> Enum.sort(fn ({a,_b}, {c,_d}) -> 
      {_char1, i1} = Enum.find(indexes, (fn {x,_i} -> x == a end)) 
      {_char2, i2} = Enum.find(indexes, (fn {y,_j} -> y == c end))
      i1 <= i2 
      end)
    |> Enum.find(fn {_char, num} -> num == 1 end)

    case first do
      {char, _num} ->
        result = Enum.find(indexes, fn {x, _i} -> char == x end)
        {_letter, index} = result
        index
      nil ->
        -1
    end

  end

end

Algos.first_unique_char_index("aabcc") # returns 2
Algos.first_unique_char_index("picadillo") # returns 0
Algos.first_unique_char_index("dood") # returns -1
```

As a sindenote, the problem is from the ["first unique character in a string"](https://leetcode.com/problems/first-unique-character-in-a-string/) LeetCode puzzle.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ **`Map`s in [tag:elixir] are not sorted by any means.**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PawełObrok While this may be on-topic on CR, in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *Needs more focus*  (as I have done here), *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Would it make sense to flag this for moderation and request a move to codereview?

Comment: @PawelObrok thank you for asking. Please see answers to [this meta question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1687/120114). Normally I would say yes if there were no answers here already but both answers to that meta point out that “_If there are answers, they would all need to be good answers on Code Review too._“ and frankly I don’t see the accepted answer here as being a good answer on CR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is probably the most performant solution; I decided to put it here because it reveals several interesting tricks.

```rb
"leetcode"
|> to_charlist()
|> Enum.with_index() # we need index to compare by
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {e, i}, acc ->
  # trick for the future: `:many > idx` for any integer `idx` :)
  Map.update(acc, e, {e, i}, &{elem(&1, 0), :many})
end)
|> Enum.sort_by(&elem(elem(&1, 1), 1)) # sort to get a head
|> case do
  [{_, {_, :many}} | _] -> "All dups"
  [{_, {result, index}} | _] -> {<<result>>, index}
  _ -> "Empty input"
end
#⇒ {"l", 0}
```

Comment: Aleksei - how do you recommend benchmarking code performance?

Comment: @Everett https://github.com/alco/benchfella or https://github.com/joekain/bmark or https://github.com/bencheeorg/benchee

Answer (score 1):

This is a good little puzzle, and one that could be solved via a couple accumulators.  Instead of splitting the string, you could work with the internal binary representation, or (in order to skip the extra complexity involved with encoding) you could convert the string to a character list and focus on the integer components.

Here's a possible solution (not thoroughly tested):

```
defmodule FirstUniq do
  def char(string) do
    [first_char | rest] = to_charlist(string)
    eval_char(first_char, 0, rest, rest)
  end

  # Case where we hit the end of the string without a duplicate!
  defp eval_char(_char, index, [], _), do: index

  # Case where a character repeats... increment the index and eval next char
  defp eval_char(char, index, [x | _], [next_char | rest]) when char == x do
    eval_char(next_char, index + 1, rest, rest)
  end

  # Case where the character does not repeat: keep looking
  defp eval_char(char, index, [x | rest], acc2) when char != x do
    eval_char(char, index, rest, acc2)
  end
end

# should be 0 (because "l" does not occur more than once)
IO.puts(FirstUniq.char("leetcode"))

# should be 2 (because "v" is the first char that does not repeat)
IO.puts(FirstUniq.char("loveleetcode"))
```

The hard work is done by the `eval_char/4` function, whose multiple clauses act something like a `case` statement.  The trick is we have to keep two accumulators, which is analogous to having a nested loop.

I would recommend [Exercism's Elixir Track](https://exercism.io/tracks/elixir) for presenting many of the common patterns that you'll encounter in the language.